# Casting Java long and double sum gives always same result

Tags: java, casting, integer-overflow

Please check this below **Java** Code:

```
public class Test{

  public static void main(String []args){
    long start = 1572544800000L;
    long end = 1635703200000L;
    int d = 10;
    int val = (int)(start + d + end + 0.0);
    // value 2147483647
    System.out.println("value: " + val); 
  }
}
```

Here if i change the value of `d` the output is always same `2147483647`. which is `Int` max value.
And if i change `0.0` to `0` the output is as expected.

Anyone can explain this behavior in `Java`

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of `start + d + end` is too large to be represented by an `int`, but it is not too large to be represented by a `long` or `double`.

By using `+ 0.0`, you are making the type of the whole expression of `start + d + end + 0.0` to be `double`. So overall you are casting a `double` to an `int`.

What happens when you convert a `double` that is too large to an `int`? The [Java Language Specification 5.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) tells you the answer:

> The value must be too large (a positive value of large magnitude or positive infinity), and the result of the first step is the largest representable value of type int or long.

If you use `0`, however, the type of the expression `start + d + end + 0` is still `long`, so you are converting a `long` to `int`, which is a different conversions. It happens like this:

> A narrowing conversion of a signed integer to an integral type T simply discards all but the n lowest order bits, where n is the number of bits used to represent type T. In addition to a possible loss of information about the magnitude of the numeric value, this may cause the sign of the resulting value to differ from the sign of the input value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will check the `Narrowing Primitive Conversion ` rule.

Answer (score -1):

2147483647 = Integer.MAX_VALUE

try

```
double val = (double)(start + d + end + 0.0);
```

or,

```
long val = (long)(start + d + end + 0.0);
```